# Adding column from one table to the other table in mysql

Tags: mysql

How to add or insert specific column from one table to other ? I tried writing like this

```
    ALTER TABLE info_apie_zaideja
    ADD SELECT info_apie_match.Rank AFTER 'Nick'
    FROM info_apie_match;
```

or this

```
    UPDATE info_apie_zaideja
    ADD COLUMN SELECT info_apie_match.Rank AFTER 'Nick'
    FROM info_apie_match;
```

but that did not work. Oh, and the table where I want to insert column is view table if that helps somehow. All answers will be appreciated.

Comment: view table does not hold any value

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this in two steps. First alter the table to add the new column:

```
ALTER TABLE info_apie_zaideja
ADD COLUMN Rank INT AFTER Nick;
```

Then fill it in by copying from corresponding rows in the other table:

```
UPDATE info_apie_zaideja AS z
JOIN info_apie_match AS m ON z.id = m.zaideja_id
SET z.Rank = m.Rank
```

I had to guess at the column that relates the two tables. Correct the `ON` clause to match your actual table relations.

Also, consider whether you really need the column in both tables. With this redundancy, you'll need to make sure that whenever you update one table, the other one is updated as well. Instead, you could just use a `JOIN` whenever you need the value from the other table.

Comment: Hey, sorry for the long delay. First of all, thanks for the answer. Second of all why do you write `AS z` and `AS m` ? Yeah, i really need the column in both tables.

Comment: Those are table aliases, so I don't have to write out the full table names every time in the query. It's easier than writing `SET info_apie_zaideja.Rank = info_apie_match.Rank`.

Comment: aha, I see. That is useful. Oh and I fixed the problem but do not really remember how. Still thanks for the answer, I am sure that it will help me out in further db development